# Paypal - Auto redirect after successful payment?

Tags: paypal

I want to redirect visitor automatically after successful payment. There are two options in Paypal and I am confused.

The first one (in the buy now button editing section)

[image]

The second one (in profile > my selling tools)

[image]

But in the second one, you can only select 1 url and that will be for all buy now buttons. That won't be good. What is the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make the auto return works you first need to turn on the "Auto Return" in your PayPal Profile and you can specify any return url there . Now if you have the multiple return url's then you should specify the  return url in your button code in the section "Take my customer to this url when they finish checkout " . In this way it will always override the return url that you have mentioned in your PayPal Profile .

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can either set it account-wide or per button: in fact, you can do both - have an account-wide default and a selective override for selected buttons. There is a third way: define the return_url variable in the POST data for the button yourself: this is another per-button override.

Which you use is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, what came in my mind is that auto redirect, or do users have to click "Return to buyer's website" button in order to be redirected ?

Comment: From memory it is the latter, and if you don't provide a return_url the link does not appear.

Comment: Is there anyway to preview "after successful payment" of my button ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting Up Auto Return Using PayPal

To set up Auto Return:

1. Log in to paypal and click Profile.
2. Click the Website Payment Preferences link under Selling Preferences.
3. Click the On radio button to enable Auto Return.
   Enter the Return URL.

Note: You must meet the Return URL requirements in order to set up Auto Return. Learn more about Return URL.

Sendbox Form Multiple Return Request URL's  : If you are using different URL's for success/failure

It will automatically overwrite paypal specified URL.